# File sharing read/write permissions

Tags: unix, permissions, google-drive-api, dropbox

I have noticed that in Dropbox, you can share a file with another user, in 'read' mode, and that viewer has the ability to share that file with others via a read-only sharable link. However, in Drive, a read-only user is unable to share a link with another user at all.

Which approach would be more similar to how the Unix/Linux approach to permissions works? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to visit the [Google Drive REST API Overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) in the official GDrive documentation specifically in the Share and collaborate section which was elaborated as:

> **apps can display a standard Google Drive sharing dialog to let users share files**

What you want to do is more on Manage Sharing:

> Access to files & folders is determined by an access control list
>   (ACL). An ACL is a list of permissions that determine whether or not
>   users can perform actions on a file such as read or write. See the
>   [permissions
>   guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-permissions)
>   for additional details about permissions and roles along with the
>   [reference
>   guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions).

Also, what want is to assign a direct file permission to the user, group or domain. It was stated to use the **`teamDrivePermissionDetails`** field to determine the use of effective role.

To see more on how to lists a file's or Team Drive permission, you can refer to the method [Permissions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list)